# Best practice for data-entry in Django admin site (different ModelAdmin on the same model)

Tags: python, django, django-admin

What's the best practices for adding a custom view to the Django Admin site for concerted data entry? I have a model *foo*, and it already has a `ModelAdmin _FooAdmin_`. This is good for editing and tweaking of data but to facilitate bulk data-entry I want to add an extra view which has a form to add, say, 20 *foo*'s at once.

I can't add another ModelAdmin as Django errors with `AlreadyRegistered: The model foo is already registered`.

I've seen in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites) that I can override `get_urls()` but this seems kind of hacky, when all I want are two slightly different `ModelAdmin`'s on the same model.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have model InspectorCheck and two ModelAdmin's classes for same model - one to show records with deleted field equal False and second to show deleted records.

This function creates new proxy model class inherited from main model:

```
def create_proxymodel(model_from, name=None, attrs=None, meta=None):
    attrs, meta = (attrs if attrs else {}, meta if meta else {})

    class  Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = model_from._meta.app_label

    for k, v in meta.items():
        setattr(Meta, k, v)

    attrs.update({'__module__': '', 'Meta': Meta})
    newmodel = type(name, (model_from,), attrs)

    return newmodel
```

**Two ModelAdmins for different purposes:**

```
class InspectorCheckAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'check_address', 'check_form', 'check_target_name')

class InspectorCheckAdminDeleted(admin.ModelAdmin): # or inherit from other ModelAdmin
    list_display = ('id', 'check_address', 'check_form', 'check_target_name', 'editor', 'updated')
    def queryset(self, request):
        return InspectorCheck.trash


#and in last step create and register both classes:

InspectorCheckDeleted = create_proxymodel(InspectorCheck, 'InspectorCheckDeleted', meta={
    'verbose_name': u'Inspector check (deleted)',
    'verbose_name_plural': u'Inspector checks (deleted)'}
)
admin.site.register(InspectorCheck, InspectorCheckAdmin)
admin.site.register(InspectorCheckDeleted, InspectorCheckAdminDeleted)
```